# NodeJS: undefined is not a new function 'new'

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I'm trying a snippet of code from the Node JS Twilio guide:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html

```
var twilio = require('twilio')('AUTH-ID','AUTH-SECRET');
    http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    resp.say({voice:'woman'}, 'ahoy hoy! Testing Twilio and node.js');
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type':'text/xml'
    });
    res.end(resp.toString());
}).listen(1337);
console.log('Visit http://localhost:1337/ in your browser to see your TwiML document!');
```

When I launch this snippet and visit the URL, I get this response:

```
/Users/unicornherder/Desktop/Porter/inbound.js:7
    var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
               ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/unicornherder/Desktop/Porter/inbound.js:7:16)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
```

Can someone kindly explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save what `require('twilio')` is exporting as that is where `TwimlResponse` lives, not on the client object that you're currently receiving (`require('twilio')(..)` is the same as `require('twilio').RestClient(..)`). So do this instead:

```
var http = require('http');

var twilio = require('twilio');
// or `var twilioClient = twilio(...)`
var twilioClient = new twilio.RestClient('AUTH-ID','AUTH-SECRET');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  resp.say({voice:'woman'}, 'ahoy hoy! Testing Twilio and node.js');
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type':'text/xml'
  });
  res.end(resp.toString());
}).listen(1337);
```

FWIW the [`twilio` docs](http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/) shows examples of using the module in this way (separating the exports from the actual Rest client).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and explaining the export process. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey @mscdex, really appreciate your help here on StackOverflow. Would love to send you a shirt to say thanks! If that sounds cool to you, email mspeir@twilio.com for details.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parameters 'AUTH-ID' and 'AUTH-SECRET' from the import.

If you pass these parameters during the import, you are initializing the rest client and the twilio variable would not be representing the module object. Therefore, TwimlResponse object would be undefined.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Taking off the auth-id and auth-secret did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking in that blog and it seems that if you are creating a response, this is all you should be requiring in your code:

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
```